Do propshafts with CV joints have any rotational orientation to them with respect to the parts they bolt into at each end?
I'm facing replacing my propshaft on this 2005 Volvo XC90 AWD and I'm looking at the 6 bolts that connect the CV joint to this flange on the rear haldex as well as the front bevel-gear / angle gear. Since the propshaft is all one piece I'm thinking it doesn't really matter which bolt hole I match the CV joints to the receiving flange but just thought I'd double check.
Here's an image of the overall propshaft in a diagram from Volvo

And here's two photos of the CV joint disassembled where you can get a clear view of the bolt holes


This is a photo of the flange mating with the cv joint on the propshaft as shown in a diagram, and just below that an actual image of the CV joint as installed in the flange on a vehicle. The left to right order of both images match up, the leftmost showing the boot, the next the CV joint itself, and the right the cap all inserting into the flange which is that large rusty cylinder in the photo.


Does bolt orientation matter?
My question has to do with the angular rotation of the CV joint into the flange and whether any particular bolt hole can go with any other so long as they line up obviously to clamp the assembly down.
Just in case a diagram helps, this is what I'm asking about, would all these bolt alignment patterns (and the other permutations) be equivalent to one another? Are there other components on the Haldex or the bevel gear which have some internal orientation to them that corresponds to the bolt hole or not really?
Bolt Orientation 1
Orientation as installed, each bolt hole matches its corresponding bolt hole as it came from the factory

Bolt Orientation 2
rotated two positions clockwise

Bolt Orientation 3
rotated three positions clockwise


I don't know for sure, but it seems to me if these had a orientation, they'd be keyed in some way or marked as such. If you're using a repair manual (ie: Haynes) or a service manual, if it doesn't say anything about it, then, no alignment required.

yah the caps are pretty symmetric, I'll add a photo that provides another angle on that part

Just realized I forgot a part of the equation too a bit, which is the drive shaft washer aka prop shaft washer. Those basically group two bolt holes together so instead of 6 rotations, we only are faced with 3. I'll see if I can get an on the ground capture of the orientation as installed in the vehicle and see what shows up with those parts relative to each other.
